# Where should schemas be maintained?

Tags: microservices, xml, schema, json-schema

When working with big architecture, I experienced high costs when it comes to changes of a data model that is used in multiple applications, servers, databases.

So I thought about designing a server with a database, whose only job is to manage schemas of a data model.

Its features should broadly and mainly be CRUD on Schemas and Versioning Schemas.
So that if a change on the data model occurs, the old version is still available if needed, thus applications depending on that model can still work.

Maybe later even stuff like Inheritance, schema transformations, specialized Access rules and supporting different file formats like JSON, XML, Java DTOs.

This way, the hope is that consumers of that server can always validate an object, can adapt to data model changes more flexible, and the schema doesn't need to be maintained in multiple projects.

The question is though: Does this kind of Micro Service make sense in an architecture that features multiple projects?
Are there "better" approaches in terms of flexibility, feasibility, maintainability that make this idea obsolete?

Or in a nutshell: Where should schemas be maintained?

Comment: Are you proposing, not just a generic repository, but a generic repository whose schema for each entity can arbitrarily change?  How would this work?  Would you require two queries: one to get the schema, and another to get the data?  Would the client have to interpret the schema before the data can be used?

Comment: Careful! Versioning schemas is simple enough - you just store the schema and its version. But making current data that conforms to the current schema somehow "magically" backwards compatible to an older schema is impossible. [Liskov will kick your b*tt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something a good old version control system such as git could handle well.

The stuff that you're versioning is basically textual in nature, and git etc. handle evolving texts pretty well.
Don't strive for much smartness in such a repository, you'll find yourself wasting time to implement features which will be rarely used. Build the smartness into the development process, for example into a good understanding of semantic versioning and decoupled deployment of evolving microservices.

For sharing schemas and code between projects, something like common libraries could be used. Typically such libraries evolve first within the context of one application and can be extracted and generalized when it is clear that they are useful in more contexts.

Whichever route you go, always consider YAGNI. As a developer, you're potentially prone to thinking that with a big generalized solution you will solve many future problems at once. Don't be caught in that trap.